# How can I sync local movement to Photon Network in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, network-programming, multiplayer, photon-pun

im making a multiplayer FPS game, and I have pretty much all the networking done and working. The issue is, that photon is syncing to players local movement, but if u have a bad connection, you could not tell it is happening cause player send late updates to the server and you can see other players lagging but you can move free and smoothly.

Im aware a lot of games work this way but i also know there are games like medal of honor that your player get stock in the last place every one else saw you. I need to know how to implement this on my game, because gameplay depends on it.

Comment: I think instead of using the normal network transform (or however it is called) you would need to implement this yourself using e.g. the `RpcTarget` options ending on `ViaServer` so all players including your local one receive the actual position from the server "at the same time" (see [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent#targets__buffering_and_order))

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is "local prediction" of actions / movement.

If I understand this right, you want clients to not act or move if there wasn't a confirmation? If so, you'd need an authoritative host or server. You'd always wait for a confirmation from the host to move the player in any way.

But .. this is not going to work well. Players will feel the lag very much and this is annoying.

You probably want to predict the movement, then correct the local situation if the server disagrees.

I would recommend using Fusion instead of PUN for shooters. It can be run with host and has a nice API to reconcile the actual state from prediction to what the host simulated.